How to upgrade the TLS on old server without reinstalling the core OS?
I'm in a rather sticky situation. Currently my server supports TLS 1.2 but not TLS 1.3 (security protocols).
It has the following installed:

Linux version 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips
Apache/2.4.37

It also has a lot of valuable content with a special setup that I don't want people to mess around with.
I read online that if I upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.2? and Apache to 2.4.38? then I can get TLS 1.3.
So I tried a similar setup on my local machine then I tried updating OpenSSL from source and it claims I need new GLIBC libraries which makes me think that I need to replace the entire operating system for OpenSSL.
Is there a way I can upgrade OpenSSL without reinstalling the OS? Or is there any other way I can enable TLS 1.3 with Apache without reinstalling the OS?

Why don’t you update the operating system? TLS 1.3 has been supported by OpenSSL for many years which suggests the underlying operating system might be outdated since you don’t already have the version that supports TLS 1.3

OpenSSL 1.0.1e? That's 11 years ago. That a version vulnerable to the critical infamous "Heartbleed" issue (might leak private key to remote attacker) - though the fix might be backported in the distribution you have.  2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 - that's 10 years old. Based on this age of what you run I suspect there are critical security issues in your software stack. Please please upgrade your system or at least put it somewhere not reachable from the internet.

except I'm not offering TLS 1.0 or 1.1 anymore Just TLS 1.2 at this time. plus I checked the websites on the server with qualsys and they have no issues

@mike_s - I think the point is that OpenSSL 1.0.1e is 11 years old. There are vulnerabilities other than just Heartbleed that you're currently vulnerable to, which goes back to the fact, what Lniux distribution are you on? The 2.6.32 kernel appears to be at least 13 years old. My suggestion upgrade to 2.6.39 at the very least.

but upgrading means doing backups of gigs of data and basically wiping out the whole OS, something that may be time consuming and costly while potentially putting on downtime for the website guests. There has to be a way to update openssl without redoing the OS.

@mike_s - You should be able to upgrade the kernel and dependencies without configuration lost, but I recommend the answer, if your hardware is older.

@Ramhound Kernel version numbering on RHEL(-likes) works in a somewhat special way. The 2.6.32 part is the least important one; that just means the kernel API/ABI stays compatible with 2.6.32 throughout the 10+ year lifecycle of the RHEL release (so that proprietary kernel modules stay compatible). The kernel continually receives both bug fixes and new major features during those years, and that's all encoded in the 431.29.2 package release number. But you still have a point in that 431.29.2 is from October 2014; the newest EL6 kernel is 754.35.1, exactly 4 years old today (EL6 is EOL)

"but upgrading means doing backups". -- please tell me you do daily backups of all important data including configuration files.

@TooTea - I am familiar with RHEL but I don’t see that mentioned in the question body. Realizing that EL6 suggests it’s RHEL though.

@RedGrittyBrick Given that the machine apparently hasn't had critical kernel security updates installed for ten years, I'm afraid that you're being way too optimistic.

@TooTea I guess you are right. The thing is I do understand why people run old stuff. For 25 years I had a Proliant 1600 running a legacy OS, it got destroyed in a flood a few months ago. The business was relocated and back in operation in days because I had it rsyncing twice a day to another server and that other server backing up twice a day to external USB drives that I rotated offsite daily. I had an spare PC set up as a cold-standby as part of the contingency plan. Its just not hard to set up something like this and no more effort to run than hanging your coat up in the morning.

see Upgrading what might be the world's oldest running Linux install which is a skip-version cross-grading-32-to-64-bit upgrade which is still entirely possible with careful planning. It's never a good idea to run outdated software

the second link gives me a 403

the hardware itself is 64-bit and the hardware was also recently upgraded with nothing wrong with software. Also, a website on the same server has ran well over 10 years with NO issue (except for when the old hardware has aged).

@mike_s has ran well over 10 years with NO issue "NO" issue? ORLY?: "OpenSSL versions 1.0.1 through 1.0.1f contain a flaw in its implementation of the TLS/DTLS heartbeat functionality. This flaw allows an attacker to retrieve private memory of an application..."  Your web server has de facto been wide open to the world for a decade.  Anything and everything on that system could have been compromised.

Nevermind all of these others:  https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-217/product_id-383/version_id-465595/Openssl-Openssl-1.0.1e.html?page=1&order=3

The 'simple' answer is 'you don't' - You run a modern supported OS and a reverse proxy to serve TLS in front of this server. This lets you keep your server setup as is, and since clients are talking to the reverse proxy, somewhat sidesteps some of the vulnerabilities from running a deeply outdated platform.  That said there's a few wrinkles beyond just doing this.
Considering the age of the OS, one might assume it's either on older, deeply EOL hardware or running as a VM.
If it's the former - I'd suggest considering that your hardware dying would result in both your unique and special setup being lost. If it's the latter, you've a lot of options, like cloning the VM, and testing the software on a supported distro. It also means you can run a second VM for the proxy
However virtualising an outdated platform should be a stopgap - and you probably should be looking at upgrading to something supported. Once you've virtualised it, you probably can look at upgrading - since upgrading a clone is almost zero risk. Alma Linux has instructions for going from CentOS 6 to 7, from which you can go to a modern Red Hat-based distro of your choice.

About 10 years ago, I had to the same thing for a Debian etch-based monolithic web server (etch become EOL in 2010, so this server was already 4 years past EOL then). This is exactly what I did: spin up an up-to-date Ubuntu VM, install nginx on it, have it do TLS termination and proxy-pass everything to the old VM. Then spun up more VMs (at the time Docker was still quite new), each running relatively independent components of the web server, and switched the proxy-pass config for each component to the new one as it passed testing. Today, I'd do the same thing, but with containers.

You don't. That server is a security nightmare.
Judging from the kernel, you're running RHEL 6, which was released in 2011, 13 years ago.

Full Support ended in 2016.
Maintenance Support ended in 2020.
Extended Life Cycle support ($800/year, doesn't cover everything) ended this year.

Your exact kernel version, 2.6.32-431.29.2, was shipped with RHEL 6.5, released in 2013. This suggests you're missing about 10 years of security updates.
On top of all this, RHEL 6 did not ship with Apache 2.4.37 (which was released in 2018), so this is a custom install. Depending on how that was done, it's possible your Apache has never received security updates.
Then there's the sites running on your server. If those are dynamic sites, perhaps using frameworks and databases, then those are also ancient, out of support, and at risk of attacks.
Your server is running ancient software that is 100% unsupported. It has not had security updates for about a decade, will never receive any new security updates. It is done. Upgrade to a more recent OS.
Let me be very clear:
It is irresponsible to keep this server connected to a network. You need to rebuild it on a modern, supported OS.

It also has a lot of valuable content with a special setup that I don't want people to mess around with.
... but upgrading means doing backups of gigs of data and basically wiping out the whole OS, something that may be time consuming and costly while potentially putting on downtime for the website guests. There has to be a way to update openssl without redoing the OS.

I feel for you, but this is the reality of (hosting) software. It needs maintenance. You cannot just leave it alone for 10+ years and expect it to be fine.
Your current situation is unsupported and insecure. This is not just about OpenSSL. The server will also break more and be increasingly harder to fix. Your comment about having to make backups also worries me. If this is important, those backups should exist already.
Rebuilding is just vital maintenance at this point. It should have been budgeted for. If not, it must be budgeted for now.

+1, but realistically, the machine apparently hasn't had critical kernel security updates installed for ten years, so whether or not the OS is still supported doesn't matter much. Even while the OS was still fully supported, the machine was already completely unmaintained, even back when updating was as simple as running yum upgrade and rebooting once in a while. I wouldn't get my hopes high that the situation will suddenly improve now when fixing the mess requires hours of work.

@TooTea You're right, I missed that (I don't usually use RHEL). That makes the situation considerably worse. I updated my answer to better reflect that.

That's why my answer focused on mitigation and virtualization first.  On the other hand I once forgot about maintenance on a personal server for about 3 years so unintentional tech debt is plausible and overwhelming . This is probably the best answer to take heed of, longer term


So I tried a similar setup on my local machine then I tried updating OpenSSL from source and it claims I need new GLIBC libraries which makes me think that I need to replace the entire operating system for OpenSSL.

It might be possible in theory to also compile a new Glibc and install it into a side directory, then compile OpenSSL to use that, and then compile Apache2 to use that.
But there is no guarantee that it'll work, especially as newer Glibc will also have raised its kernel requirements as well.

but upgrading means doing backups of gigs of data and basically wiping out the whole OS, something that may be time consuming and costly while potentially putting on downtime for the website guests.

It absolutely does not mean that. It means starting up a new server alongside the existing one, copying data and configuration from the server over to the new one, then switching your DNS domain name to the new IP address. (Or swapping the IP addresses, or changing the 'port forwarding' rules, etc.)
You can set up the new server over a week or however much it takes, then switch over with only a few minutes of downtime.

You're stuck in a vicious cycle of dependencies, because your system is outdated. You can build a current glibc from source to address the immediate error. Install glibc outside the path, so that the old one is still available for your old apps. But your next error is going to be that your kernel is too old for that glibc. If you build a new kernel from source, it won't be compatible with your old libc
A workaround for this with some apps is to find an AppImage binary (works OK for new Firefox versions on outdated Linux). But I wouldn't trust an AppImage for something as important as OpenSSL
You're past the time for workarounds. Follow the other advice here - upgrade
Finally, there are several alternatives to OpenSSL - GnuTLS is the next most popular. But it's likely you'll get stuck in the same libc -> kernel trap

AppImage is for applications. It does not work for libraries (such as OpenSSL) that other applications need to use. It is not a viable solution for this.

Thanks for pointing out GnuTLS but I'm wondering how I can get it to work with apache. maybe there's an apache module that I can use that can allow me to use GnuTLS. I'm not sure. But people telling me to upgrade everything JUST for one item is an overkill. its like spending $1,000,000 for ONE banana.

@mike_s Please read my answer. It is not about "just one thing".

I'm not so certain you get stuck; likes you can static link gnutls against musl libc and its two other library dependencies; then static link apache from there.

@mike_s A more apt metaphor would be "Why are they asking me to spend $1,000,000 for some tubes ?" when your whole installation is using contaminated and leaking lead water pipes that you have to remove from the walls before somebody get lead poisoning or your whole building get flooded from a pipe rupture

@mike_s Welcome to technical debt. You have a server that is at best a security nightmare. At worst it's not your server anymore.

What are you serving from the Apache server? - I ask because there are lighterweight alternatives that can be statically linked all the way down. - Alternatively you can build your own newer OpenSSL, or use a different SSL library like others have recommended. E.g., https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Apache_HTTP_Server/mod_gnutls
If you really can't upgrade things the vendor recommended way, then maintain a separate tree of all dependencies [e.g., by hand or using Arch Linux's pacman or NiXOS' nixpkgs], and change your init script for apache to use this apache server. Then the only major thing left to worry about is the kernel. Guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman or https://nix.dev/manual/nix#chap-installation
Finally, it's not difficult to manually upgrade the kernel; if you can't use your proper system package manager (e.g., because everything on your system is EOL); for example, by following this guide: https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/kernel_administration_guide/ch-manually_upgrading_the_kernel#s1-kernel-packages
This solution isn't perfect, for a start: you'll also have to consider upgrading your glibc, networking stack, software firewall, and logging subsystems. Upgrading to a supported version of a well-known Linux distribution is recommended.

I have tried to upgrade RHEL 7 to RHEL 8.  I was unsucessful. At the time both the version of RHEL 7 I was using and the version of RHEL I was going to use was supported. I spent over 10 hours trying to resolve one issue that blocked the upgrade.

Strong accusation for an Anonymous system but let’s assume I was the single person to cast a single downvote. The answer doesn’t go into any detail and the only thing I can speak to is that upgrading RHEL7 to 8 was very difficult (I wasn’t successful) so I can’t imagine 6 to 8. What the error was, isn’t important, if I wanted help with that one I would go directly to other RHEL administrators. My problem isn’t relevant to the question but my difficulty of doing what you suggested in the answer is relevant (suggesting it’s not as easy as you suggested)

Did you try using an alternative package manager which creates its own tree of dependencies, install Apache Web Server there, and then changing your init script to point to this Apache?

Who is supposed to answer that question?

@mike_s / OP. My suggestion is reasonable, and may answer his question.
